# Select observations close to their neighbor in scatter plots

Tags: r, select, distance

I have a dataset `ind` with two population `fr2100` and `nr`, where each individual in this population have an unique numerous. Each individual has coordinates, a `Dim.1` and `Dim.2` value. As you can see here:

```
> ind <- get_pca_ind(res_acp)
> ind
Principal Component Analysis Results for individuals
 ===================================================
  Name       Description                       
1 "$coord"   "Coordinates for the individuals" 
2 "$cos2"    "Cos2 for the individuals"        
3 "$contrib" "contributions of the individuals"

# isolate the population 'fr2100'
> fr2100 <- ind$coord[substr(rownames(ind$coord), 1, 7) == 'fr2100_', ]
> str(fr2100)
'data.frame':   6873 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ rowname: chr  "fr2100_72" "fr2100_73" "fr2100_74" "fr2100_75" ...
 $ Dim.1  : num  1.37 1.3 1.25 1.25 1.18 ...
 $ Dim.2  : num  -1.249 -1.028 -0.835 -0.624 -0.483 ...

# isolate the population 'nr'
> nr <- ind$coord[substr(rownames(ind$coord), 1, 3) == 'nr_', ]
> str(nr)
'data.frame':   4897 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ rowname: chr  "nr_174" "nr_175" "nr_176" "nr_177" ...
 $ Dim.1  : num  -3.74 -3.44 -3.26 -2.97 -3.88 ...
 $ Dim.2  : num  1.26 1.55 1.7 1.91 1.3 ...
```

**My question:** I am trying to understand how I can select only, among the 6873 individuals of `fr2100`, the individuals who have a value of `Dim.1` AND `Dim.2` at a distance of more or less 0.01 from the 4897 individuals `nr`, represented in this cloud of points:
[image]

In other words, each individuals `fr2100` that can be within the perimeter (at 0.01) of an individual `nr`. as theoretically represented here

[image]

I'm interested in any answers. I can provide more information if needed. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess `distance_semi_join()` from [fuzzyjoin package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/fuzzyjoin/) would be rather straightforward and compact way to filter by euclidean distance. Other variants like `distance_left_join()` are also worth considering as those will provide an optional distance variable in resulting dataframe.

```r
library(fuzzyjoin)
library(ggplot2)

# example datasets
set.seed(1)
nr <- data.frame(rowname = paste0("nr_", 1:100), Dim.1 = rnorm(100, -0.05, 0.03), Dim.2 = rnorm(100, 0, 0.02))
fr <- data.frame(rowname = paste0("fr_", 1:100), Dim.1 = rnorm(100,  0.05, 0.03), Dim.2 = rnorm(100, 0, 0.02))

# fr points within distance of closest nr point:
fr_in_dist <- distance_semi_join(fr, nr, 
                                 by = c("Dim.1","Dim.2"), 
                                 max_dist=0.01)

fr_in_dist
#>    rowname        Dim.1         Dim.2
#> 5     fr_5 -0.018557066  3.308291e-02
#> 14   fr_14  0.008893764 -1.311564e-02
#> 18   fr_18  0.012401307 -2.420202e-03
#> 25   fr_25  0.015302829  9.640590e-03
#> 28   fr_28  0.001834598  3.409789e-03
#> 32   fr_32 -0.036667620 -3.138164e-02
#> 38   fr_38  0.014406241  8.797409e-05
#> 46   fr_46 -0.010004948 -2.817701e-02
#> 57   fr_57 -0.022092886 -2.347154e-02
#> 68   fr_68  0.014326601  1.135904e-02
#> 77   fr_77 -0.018673719  2.577108e-03
#> 79   fr_79  0.010512645 -3.278219e-03
#> 84   fr_84  0.028963050  3.286837e-03
#> 86   fr_86  0.019967835 -1.130428e-03
#> 94   fr_94  0.007212280  6.132097e-03

ggplot() +
  geom_point(data = nr, aes(x = Dim.1, y = Dim.2, color = "nr"))+
  geom_point(data = fr, aes(x = Dim.1, y = Dim.2, color = "fr"))+
  geom_point(data = fr_in_dist, aes(x = Dim.1, y = Dim.2), shape = 1, size = 5 )+
  coord_fixed() +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

---

Original answer was about singe reference point vs point could, in this `dist()` from base is also quite straightforward:

```r
library(ggplot2)

# sample data, add point fr2100_xx that would fall outside of the perimeter
df <- read.csv(text = "rowname, Dim.1, Dim.2
fr2100_72, 0.003810163, 0.006935450
fr2100_73, 0.003433946, 0.004698691
fr2100_74, 0.003168248, 0.003097222
fr2100_xx, 0.015, 0.015")

# nr and threshold distance
nr <- c(0.0035, 0.005)
thr_dist <- 0.01

# insert nr point to first position to use it in distance matrix calculation
dist_m <- rbind(c(0.0035, 0.005),df[,c("Dim.1", "Dim.2")]) |> dist() |> as.matrix()

# distances: 
as.dist(dist_m)
#>              1            2            3            4
#> 2 0.0019601448                                       
#> 3 0.0003084643 0.0022681777                          
#> 4 0.0019314822 0.0038915356 0.0016233602             
#> 5 0.0152397507 0.0137930932 0.0154884012 0.0167829223

# extract first column, distnaces from point "nr" ([1,1] = 0)
df$dist <-dist_m[-1,1]
# flag points that fall outside of the perimeter
df$in_dist = df$dist <= thr_dist
df
#>     rowname       Dim.1       Dim.2         dist in_dist
#> 1 fr2100_72 0.003810163 0.006935450 0.0019601448    TRUE
#> 2 fr2100_73 0.003433946 0.004698691 0.0003084643    TRUE
#> 3 fr2100_74 0.003168248 0.003097222 0.0019314822    TRUE
#> 4 fr2100_xx 0.015000000 0.015000000 0.0152397507   FALSE
```

Viz - https://i.stack.imgur.com/rrAVx.png

Comment: Thank you for your answer, very good suggestion to use `dist()`. I'm sorry if my first edit was vague. I try to determine the distance not just of some `fr2100` points to one `nr`but of 6873 `fr2100` points to 4897 `nr`points! My graph was theoric, I am not trying to reproduce it but it was to illustrate what I am trying to do for each `nr` points (in orange on the graph). So, I try to use your suggestion in my case, but I have a problem, as you can see at the end of my new edit. Maybe you have some ideas to solve it, feel free to edit your answer and my question to make it more clear. Thx

Comment: Updated . Moved to fuzzyjoin for compactness, though dist() should scale without too much fiddling.  As would pretty much everything with "nearest neighbour" in its description.

Comment: Thanks for your update, this is exactly what I wanted to have! It works perfectly, I am impressed. Thank you.